# Delete Row / Remove Row

Tags: vb.net, gridview, rows

I want to delete my rows in gridview, but when I try many code the error are same.

When I try this

```
Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection(PyrDLL.Koneksi.ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "xyz"
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon
            sqlCon.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            da.Fill(dt)
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt
            Gridview1.DataBind()
            sqlCon.Close()
            If Gridview1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Dim dtempty As DataTable = Nothing
                dtempty = (DirectCast(Gridview1.DataSource, DataTable)).Clone()
                dtempty.Rows.Add(dtempty.NewRow())
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtempty
                Gridview1.DataBind()
                Gridview1.Rows(0).Visible = False
                'Gridview1.Rows(0).Controls.Clear()
            Else
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    dt.Rows(i)("rupiah") = PyrDLL.Decrypt(dt.Rows(i)("rupiah"))
                    dt.Rows(i)("rupiah") = Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows(i)("rupiah")).ToString()
                    'i = i + 1
                Next
                Gridview1.DataBind()
                For i As Integer = Gridview1.Rows.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
                    Dim row As GridViewRow = Gridview1.Rows(i)
                    Dim prevrow As GridViewRow = Gridview1.Rows(i - 1)
                    If (TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("lblketerangan"), Label).Text.ToString() = TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(1).FindControl("lblketerangan"), Label).Text.ToString()) And (TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("lblcomp"), Label).Text.ToString() = TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(0).FindControl("lblcomp"), Label).Text.ToString()) Then
                        Dim total As Integer = Convert.ToDecimal(TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).FindControl("lblrupiah"), Label).Text)
                        Dim total2 As Integer = Convert.ToDecimal(TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(2).FindControl("lblrupiah"), Label).Text)
                        Dim total3 As Decimal
                        total3 = total + total2
                        DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(2).FindControl("lblrupiah"), Label).Text = Decimal.Parse(total3).ToString()
                        row.Visible = False
                        'Gridview1.Rows.Remove(Gridview1.Rows(i)) <--- if i comment here its run without problem
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

the error

***Remove' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'***

Can you help me?

now, i hide the row after i sum it but i want to auto delete / remove row after i sum it not only hide

Thanks

Comment: Are you data binding the grid? As in setting it's `DataSource` property? If so you should remove the data from the data source and re-bind instead of trying to manipulate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do when there are no rows, the gridview would be empty

You should do the following instead:

```
'Call GetData() every time you want to bind data to the gridview
Private Function GetData()

    Gridview1.DataSource = Nothing
    Gridview1.DataBind()

    Dim strQuery = "SELECT..."
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection(PyrDLL.Koneksi.ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlCon)
        'Add cmd parameters as required to prevent SqlInjection
        sqlCon.Open()

            Using ada As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                ada.Fill(dt)
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt
                Gridview1.DataBind()
            End Using

        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

When handling the data in the gridview you can use RowDataBound, you could then call a separate function to handle deleting a row after your logic is handled where the criteria is met to delete a row

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'Handle databound logic
    End If
End Sub
```

You should be able to tailor this to your needs, just called GetData() everytime you need to rebind data to the gridview

Comment: i was show all code now, i hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem
i cant remove rows from data gridview but i remove data from data table and bind it after thats
thanks everyone